# Check empty input jquery - loop through array of elements

Tags: jquery, string

I've added a new property to input that I require to be filled: `data-required` (in spanish).

I have 3 or 4 in my form, I loop them this way:

```
$('#impFormularios').submit( function() {
    $(":input[data-requerido]").each( function() {
      if( $(this).val == '' ) {
        alert('hola');
      }
    });
  });
```

But my alert is not showing. I think it's because i'm doing something wrong with `val` since the console log shows JQuery code for each item.val value (in console.log).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `val` with jQuery object. You can use value attribute as well but with DOM object.

Change

```
if( $(this).val == '' ) {
```

To

```
if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
```

Or

```
if( this.value == '' ) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I still miss to add the () because I think its a property of the element... I will post a sticky note on my monitor lol

Comment: You can use value property with DOM object, check my updated answer.

Comment: Consider changing `==` to `===`.